# Named routes in ActionMailer tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I am sending invitations via e-mail containing a confirmation link. In my functional test I want to check if the mail body contains the correct URL like this:

```
class InvitationSenderTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  test "invite" do
    ...
    url = new_user_url(:www_host => 'localhost', :confirm_key => invitation.confirm_key)
    assert_match /http:\/\/localhost#{url}/, mail.body.encoded
  end
end
```

On the line starting with `url =`, the test gets an error saying `undefined method 'new_user_url'`, while in an ActionController test, the same line works with no problem.

I tried inserting the lines:

```
include ActionDispatch::Routing
include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
```

inside the class definition, but to no avail. I also tried using `url_for`, but that doesn't work either ("undefined local variable or method '_routes'"). I guess I need some import here, but which?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include the dynamically generated url helpers module, and then use any url helper defined by it like so:

```
class InvitationSenderTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  test "invite" do
    ...
    url = new_user_url(:www_host => 'localhost', :confirm_key => invitation.confirm_key)
    assert_match /http:\/\/localhost#{url}/, mail.body.encoded
  end
end
```